# PostgreSQL select query to parse YAML string to JSON for JSONB type column

Tags: json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.10 on the Ubuntu machine. I need to write a SQL query to select data from JSONB column. But JSONB column contains the data in YAML format as string not in JSON format.

Database JSONB field return below data:

`"---\nemployee:\n reference: '6'\n first_name: Test\n last_name: Test\n email: test@test.test.edu\n new_title: Manager in Training\n former_title: N/A\n annual_salary: 5000000\n new_salary_grade: '10'\n annual_salary_currency: USD\n former_salary_grade: N/A\norigin_address:\n country_alpha3: USA\n country_name: USA\n"`

if we have JSON data from JSONB column like:

`{"employee": {"reference": "6", "first_name": "Test", "last_name": "Test", "email": "test@test.test.edu", "new_title": "Manager in Training", "former_title": "N/A", "annual_salary": 5000000, "new_salary_grade": "10", "annual_salary_currency": "USD", "former_salary_grade": "N/A"}, "origin_address": {"country_alpha3": "USA", "country_name": "USA"}}`

then we can write SQL query on JSONB column like:

`select test_field->'employee'->'first_name' as name from employees;`

But this query is not working on JSONB column when the column returns the YAML string.

I didn't find any predefined function or regular expression to parse YAML string to JSON format in a SQL query.

Please help me to make the SQL query on JSONB column for YAML string format data.

Thanks!

Comment: now can jsonb contain not json?.. maybe it is text column?..

Comment: column type is jsonb, but data in that column is YAML string format.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, hopefully somebody can answer this.

Comment: Why do you have YAML string in JSONB column?